# Rを使用して列の合計値を計算、各列の合計値が100以上の列のみを抽出する方法

Tags: r, tidyverse

Rを使用して、列の合計値を計算、列の合計値が100以上の列のみを抽出してデータフレームにする方法を教えていただけますでしょうか。

df <- data.frame(id=1:3, score1 = c(200, 30, 100), score2=c(0, 30, 10), score3=c(90, 40, 10), score4=c(200, 220, 300))

上記のようなデータフレームです。よろしくお願いいたします

Comment: サンプルデータやデータフレームを作成するまでのコードはありませんか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tidyverse` を使う場合。

```r
suppressMessages(library(tidyverse))

df <- data.frame(id=1:3, score1 = c(200, 30, 100), score2=c(0, 30, 10), score3=c(90, 40, 10), score4=c(200, 220, 300))

df2 <- df %>% select(id, where(~sum(.[.!="id"], na.rm=T) >= 100))
df2

#   id score1 score3 score4
# 1  1    200     90    200
# 2  2     30     40    220
# 3  3    100     10    300
```

Comment: idの変数にはselect_if(~ sum(., na.rm=T) >= 100)を適応しないまま、df2に残す方法はありますか？

Comment: 回答を更新しました。